# OpenRowSet - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am using `Openrowset` function of SQL Server to read data from excel files.

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0','Excel 8.0;Database=E:\IGM\Files\cis overview.xls;HDR=No;IMEX=1;','SELECT * FROM [CIS Overview$]')
```

But not all columns are being shown by `openrowset`.

Below is just sample, the Excel file which I am reading has 28 columns, and 27 having no data in it, just heading, and 28 is ignored by `Openrowset`.

```
col1 col2 col3
--------------
 A         X
 B         X
 C         X
 .         .
 .         .
```

`Openrowset` is not returning `col3` in resultset - why?

Its only showing col1, col2.

But if i insert some data in col2(any cell), result set will have all three columns.

It is ignoring last column if previous has no data?

I also include `HDR=NO` option in query, but no luck?

Is their any way to get all columns in result set?

any help?

regards,

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space from your worksheet tab name: "CIS Overview" --> "CIS_Overview" or "CISOverview".

Answer (score 0):

If you know number of columns you can try to specify if in a query to excel list:

```
'SELECT * FROM [CIS Overview$A:Z]'
```

here columns goes from 'A' to 'Z'.

Comment: still the same problem. As 28 columns are their, i tried A:AB. still not showing last column. If i test with A:K, A:Z its working. But with A:AB Not showing last column.